# Web2py: Internal error on running

Tags: python, web2py

I get this error

> Internal error Ticket issued: unrecoverable

When trying to run web2py from https://github.com/web2py/web2py/tree/e1bb2b4556352612a8f0386373d23e49f3e138c4

I am using ubuntu 12.04, and already have web2py 1.99.4. But I want to check the new version. As stated in the repo's readme, I should just simply run python web2py.py

But, when I start the server, I found internal error.

Below is what I get from the shell:

```
gofrendi@arcaneSanctum:~/Documents/web2py-web2py-e1bb2b4$ python web2py.py -M
web2py Web Framework
Created by Massimo Di Pierro, Copyright 2007-2012
Version 2.0.9 (2012-10-07 01:10:05) dev
Database drivers available: SQLite(sqlite2), SQLite(sqlite3), MySQL(pymysql), MySQL(MySQLdb), PostgreSQL(psycopg2), PostgreSQL(pg8000), CouchDB(couchdb), IMAP(imaplib)
please visit:
    http://127.0.0.1:8000
starting browser...
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
Created new window in existing browser session.
ERROR:web2py:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gofrendi/Documents/web2py-web2py-e1bb2b4/gluon/main.py", line 614, in wsgibase
    BaseAdapter.close_all_instances('rollback')
  File "/home/gofrendi/Documents/web2py-web2py-e1bb2b4/gluon/dal.py", line 525, in close_all_instances
    for db_uid, db_group in dbs:
NameError: global name 'dbs' is not defined

ERROR:web2py:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gofrendi/Documents/web2py-web2py-e1bb2b4/gluon/main.py", line 614, in wsgibase
    BaseAdapter.close_all_instances('rollback')
  File "/home/gofrendi/Documents/web2py-web2py-e1bb2b4/gluon/dal.py", line 525, in close_all_instances
    for db_uid, db_group in dbs:
NameError: global name 'dbs' is not defined

ERROR:web2py:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gofrendi/Documents/web2py-web2py-e1bb2b4/gluon/main.py", line 614, in wsgibase
    BaseAdapter.close_all_instances('rollback')
  File "/home/gofrendi/Documents/web2py-web2py-e1bb2b4/gluon/dal.py", line 525, in close_all_instances
    for db_uid, db_group in dbs:
NameError: global name 'dbs' is not defined

ERROR:web2py:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gofrendi/Documents/web2py-web2py-e1bb2b4/gluon/main.py", line 614, in wsgibase
    BaseAdapter.close_all_instances('rollback')
  File "/home/gofrendi/Documents/web2py-web2py-e1bb2b4/gluon/dal.py", line 525, in close_all_instances
    for db_uid, db_group in dbs:
NameError: global name 'dbs' is not defined

ERROR:web2py:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gofrendi/Documents/web2py-web2py-e1bb2b4/gluon/main.py", line 614, in wsgibase
    BaseAdapter.close_all_instances('rollback')
  File "/home/gofrendi/Documents/web2py-web2py-e1bb2b4/gluon/dal.py", line 525, in close_all_instances
    for db_uid, db_group in dbs:
NameError: global name 'dbs' is not defined
```

So, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That commit is just broken. If you look at the code, the `dbs` variable never gets defined, so the `close_all_instances` function will always fail. There's a bug report for it: [web2py issue #1072](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/issues/detail?id=1072)

You can apply the patch above yourself, or use my [patch-1](https://github.com/dbarnett/web2py/tree/patch-1) branch where I've applied the patch (and sent a pull request), or you can use the commit just before the code was broken ([231a3e1278](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/tree/231a3e127884ef37dfbbde77d138e544811ff0ef)), or just wait for it to get fixed in master which I'd assume will happen soon.